# Reset formvalidation.io validation elements in the form in Fuelux wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, fuelux, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using FuelUX wizard along with the validation plugin available on formvalidation.io.

I'm trying to reset the form elements so that I could again use the same form and validate as a new fresh form.
The form get's clear, but the validation doesn't. It consider's the form as validated, even if the form elements are cleared.